# How to compute $\det(A+J)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

If $A$  be an $n\times n$ matrix and $J$ be a matrix of same order with all entries $1$ then

> Show that $\det( A + J)=\det A$ + sum of all cofactors of $A$.

I have tried using Laplace Expansion but I am not getting it.

Please give some hints at doing the same.

Comment: Hint: Try induction

Comment: If you consider $\det(A+xJ)$, perhaps you will see how the coefficient of $x^{n-k}$ will involve the $k\times k$ cofactors of $A$? Then you can set $x=1$ afterwards.

Comment: Particular case of the following fact: If $A$ is an $n\times n$-matrix, if $u$ is an $n\times 1$-matrix (i.e., a column vector of size $n$), and if $v$ is an $1\times n$-matrix (i.e., a row vector of size $n$), then $\det\left(A+uv\right) = \det A + v \left(\operatorname{adj} A\right) u$, where $\operatorname{adj} A$ denotes the adjugate of $A$ (that is, the transpose of the cofactor matrix of $A$). Your claim follows from this fact when all coordinates of $u$ and $v$ are $1$. The fact is rather well-known (see, e.g., problem 3.1 in Chapter I of ...

Comment: ... Prasolov's http://www2.math.su.se/~mleites/books/prasolov-1994-problems.pdf , or Solution to Additional exercise 23 in my https://github.com/darijgr/detnotes/releases/tag/2016-05-29 , or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_determinant_lemma , although the latter page currently pretends that every matrix is invertible).

Comment: Is the intention of the exercise for you to use Laplace, or would you like to see a formula that can deal with this?

Comment: Yes I am ready for other alternatives@J.M.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Let $a_1,\dots,a_n$ be the columns of $A$ and let $v_0$ be the vector $(1,1,\dots,1)$. When you expand $\det(a_1+v_0,\dots,a_n+v_0)$ according to multilinearity of the determinant, then apart from $\det(A)$ you only get $n$ further summands which can be non-zero. The latter summands can be easily computed by expansion along their "special column".

**Edit**: The $n$ potentially non-zero additional summands are of the form $\det(a_1,\dots,a_{i-1},v_0,a_{i+1},\dots,a_n)$. Computing this determinant by expansion with respect to the $i$th column (the one containing $v_0$) you get a sum of cofactors of $A$ (with appropriate signs).

Comment: What is meant by "special column"?

Comment: I got $\det A$ from the expansion but I am not getting the term of "sum of all cofactors of $A$" ;Please help

Comment: I have edited the answer to provide more hints.