# How to compute the given determinant?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

This is in association with this problem:[How to compute $\det(A+J)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1807912/186473)

As I could not find suitable answers so I am posing this question with my following attempt:

On expanding $\det(A+J)$ by Laplace Expansion :

Let us expand corresponding to the 1st row then we will get $(a_{11}+1)\text{cofactor ($a_{11}+1$)}+(a_{12}+1)\text{cofactor ($a_{12}+1$)}+\dots+(a_{ij}+1)\text{cofactor ($a_{ij}+1$)}+\ldots +a_{1n}\text{cofactor ($a_{1n}+1$)}$

Note that $\text{cofactor ($a_{11}+1$)}=\det A_{11}^{'}$
where $A_{11}^{'}$ will be an $n-1\times n-1$ matrix

Also $A_{11}^{'}=A_{11}+J$.
By induction hypothesis $\det A_{11}^{'}=\det A_{11}+\sum $of all cofactors of $A_{11}$

If we consider all the terms in the expansion of $\det (A+J)$ then we get :
\begin{equation}
\det (A+J)=\det(A)+\{\ldots \ldots \} 
\end{equation}

**I have to prove that the term in the above bracket is = $\text{sum of all cofactors of A}$**

How should I proceed ?
Please give some hints.